# Lock profiling in 2.6 linux kernel

Tags: linux, profiling, kernel, locking

How can I do the lock profiling (spin and other kind of locks) in 2.6 Linux kernel? I want to get the lock contention numbers for few locks which I have added in my module. Is there any .config option which I can enable and get the profile or any other tool?

Answer (score 2):

Andrew Thanks for good pointer.

Looks like oprofile cannot give lock statistics. CONFIG_LOCK_STAT is present only after 2.6.23 kernel. While my kernel version is 2.6.16. If kernel version is <2.6.23 then lockmeter patch (http://oss.sgi.com/projects/lockmeter/) is the option.

Answer (score 1):

[OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/)'s docs say that you can use it to profile the kernel. Though, it seems there is a better alternative - compiling the kernel with the following config option:

```
CONFIG_LOCK_STAT=y
```

There's a [blog entry describing it in more details](http://dolavim.us/blog/2007/11/06/linux-kernel-lock-profiling-with-lockstat/).

Full Disclaimer - I did not try it myself, merely read about it.